# Remove day from date format in php

Tags: php

Can someone help me please, I need a function or a way in PHP, to exclude the day from a given date regardless of its format.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

try this

```
$newdate = date("m-Y",strtotime($date));
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need to keep the original format of the date!

Comment: @ElieHaber: You can have any time format as you need. pls see http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Yes, but the format of the original date is unknown for me, I need to exclude the date from any given date format input, and the output must be in the same format, so I can't transform to a specific format after  excluding the date!

Comment: How can you expect to preserve the original format, stripping out the day, if you don't know that format? If you don't know the format, the day could be anywhere in the string.

Comment: @ElieHaber - What have you done so far? Have you even done any research into this matter?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this as well, and made preg match to check for 2 date formats with year notation yyyy. Not the solution I'd prefer, but it works for me. Downside is that you have to define all the date formats and it depends on yyyy notation.

```
    // check form to be yyyy-mm-dd
    if (preg_match('/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$/D', $date)){
        $date = date("Y-m", $date);
    }
    // check form to be mm-dd-yyyy
    elseif (preg_match('/^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}$/D', $date)){
        $date = date("m-Y", $date);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am answering this for people who have encountered the same problem

```
if (!function_exists('remove_days_in_date')) {
    /**
     * This function allows you to delete some number of days in a date
     * @param \DateTime $date The date in which to delete the days
     * @param int $n_day The number of days to delete
     * @return string
     */
    function remove_days_in_date(\DateTime $date, int $n_day) {
        
        date_sub($date,date_interval_create_from_date_string("$n_day days"));
        date_format($date,"Y-m-d h:i:s");

        return date_format($date,"Y-m-d h:i:s");
    }
}
echo remove_days_in_date(new \DateTime, 12);
```